# How to query the sys_user table using REST?

Tags: python, servicenow

I am using v2.0.1 of [servicenow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/servicenow/2.0.1) from PyPi to interact with ServiceNow. I need to be able to look up a user in the sys_user table so I can find the sys_id assigned to them. If anyone has some sample code they can share it would be appreciated.

I have tried using the following with no success:

```
from servicenow import Connection
from servicenow import ServiceNow

conn = conn = Connection.Auth(username='abc', password='xyz', instance='demo')
user = ServiceNow.Base(conn)
user.__table__ = 'sys_user.do'

rec = user.fetch_all({'user_name': 'abc123'})
```

This fails with

```
AttributeError: 'Base' object has no attribute 'fetch_all'
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with PyPi, but I will tell you you can make standard REST calls to the /api/now/table/sys_user?sysparm_query=user_nameSTARTSWITH

Also, make sure to review the notes regarding JSON, JSONv2, vs SOAP and use the right connection auth string